# Preserving data format Decimal(6,5) from vba to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sqldatatypes

I am moving data from Excel to SQL using VBA and Stored procedures. One of my fields Sensor_Measure is of data type Decimal(6,5) in SQL. The stored procedure is like this:

```
Alter Procedure dbo.SP_Sensor  
(  
@Name varhchar(4),    
@Sensor_D varchar(10)  
)  
Declare  
@iSensor Decimal(6,5)  
@iSensor=@Sensor  
Insert into dbo.SensorTble Values(@Name,@iSensor )
```

My VBA code is like this:

```
Dim Name, Sensor as String  
Dim oName, oSensor as ADODB.Parameter  

Name=ws.Cells(2,3)  
Sensor=ws.Cells(4,5)   
Set oSensor = cmd.CreateParameter("@Sensor_D", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, Sensor)
        cmd.Parameters.Append oSensor  
cmd.Execute
```

In the excel workbook the data point for Sensor is

> 0.000121778

but when it goes to sql it looks like this

> 1.21778

What I should be looking at is

> 0.00012

. Where am i going wrong.

Comment: Look at your `CreateParameter` call - you're passing it as `adVarChar(30)` instead of `adDecimal`.

Comment: @Dai Yes I am doing all the conversions in SQL to reduce debugging in VBA. In any case, I did try adDecimal with NumericScale and Precision but got the "Invalid Scale Value" error

Comment: I would suggest converting the data up front, and only deal with passing data of Decimal type from Excel through to SQL Server.

Comment: @HardCode what is the reason for recommending conversion in Excel?

Comment: There is more room for errors when passing a string data type, that needs to be ultimately converted to a decimal, all long the chain. For example, if you cast to Decimal right at the beginning, the issue of "Excel was sending 1.223523515E-4 to SQL" would have been avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel was sending 1.223523515E-4 to SQL and SQL didnt recognize the E-4 part and was giving me 1.22. So I did this in Excel:

```
SENSOR_ = Format(ws.Cells(4, 5), "0.######")
```

This fixed my problem